# Why systemLayoutSizeFittingSize method is called on each UICollectionViewCell even if the cells have fixed size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, smooth-scrolling

I have made a collection view with a flow layout that scrolls horizontally. The cells should have a fixed width and should fill the collection view vertically. So I have set this fixed size using the flow layout property `itemSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of my controller.

```
myCollectionViewFlow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(MyCollectionViewColumnWidth, myCollectionView.frame.size.height);
```

I do not give an estimated item size to the layout so, according to the Apple's documentation about property `estimatedItemSize` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, I do not expect that the collection view queries the size of each cell using the cell’s `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:` method.

> The default value of this property is CGSizeZero. Setting it to any other value causes the collection view to query each cell for its actual size using the cell’s preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes: method. If all of your cells are the same height, use the itemSize property, instead of this property, to specify the cell size instead.

However, by analysing the call tree using the time profiler on iOS 9 simulator, I have observed that the `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:` method is called on each cell. The default implementation of this method seems to calculate the subview's layout according to the constraints. As my cells are complex this takes much times, so this avoids to obtain a smooth scrolling.

I have fixed the performance issue by overriding the `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:` method and returning the target size (as my cells have fixed size).

```
- (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority
{
    return targetSize;
}
```

But I cannot understand why I need to do this trick with the configuration I set. And I am also afraid of causing unexpected behavior by subclassing this method.

**EDIT**

The `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:` method is not called on iOS 10 simulator nor on iOS 10 device. Unfortunately, I don't have device with iOS 9 to test so I can't determine if it is just a bug of the simulator.

Comment: mention code of reload collectionview .

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What code do you want that I mention ? My implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Because I do not reload the data after the initial loading. The `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:`method is called by the system when the collection layout its subviews during scrolling

Comment: how to reload your collectionView that mention here .